# phantom-node not passing return value from page.evaluate function

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, rect

I am trying to extract a specific element of a webpage, and save it as an image locally.

node.js code, using phantom-node:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create().then(function(ph) {

  ph.createPage().then(function(page) {

    page.property('viewportSize', {width: 1600, height: 900});
    page.open('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570827/saving-element-of-webpage-as-an-image-using-js').then(function(status) {

        if (status == 'success') {
            page.evaluate(function() {
                return document.getElementById("sidebar").getBoundingClientRect(); 

            }).then(function(rect){
                console.log(rect);
                page.property('clipRect', rect);
                page.render("question2.png"); 
            });   
        }
        page.close();
        ph.exit();
    });
  });
});
```

console.log(rect) prints different values every time I run it. I don't see why that would be the case, but either way, I guess my return statement of the sidebar bounding rect isn't working. Is there something wrong with the code?

Edit: actually, after further debugging, it seems that the rect is being returned properly, but not being set to clipRect..

Comment: Yes, it makes sense that different values are printed every time, because the content always changes.

Comment: The problem is that it's always rendering the full page, instead of the sidebar element. I want a specific part of the page.

Comment: Have you tried to call `render` in a separate `then` callback?

Comment: @ArtjomB. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570827/saving-element-of-webpage-as-an-image-using-js

it was working the way I want with just phantom.js

Comment: @ArtjomB. yes, doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the page.render call did not have enough time to finish before page.close() occurred.

This code solves the problem:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create().then(function(ph) {

    ph.createPage().then(function(page) {

        page.open('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570827/saving-element-of-webpage-as-an-image-using-js').then(function(status) {

            if (status == 'success') {
                page.evaluate(function() {
                    return document.getElementById("sidebar").getBoundingClientRect();
                }).then(function(rect){
                    page.property('clipRect', rect);
                    page.render("question.png").then(function(){
                        page.close();
                        ph.exit();
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```